# How to construct a homeomorphism on closed unit disc onto itself which fixes boundary point wise?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, analysis, differential-geometry

How can we construct a homeomorphism on closed disc onto itself which fixes boundary pointwise? What is the starting point.

Comment: You could use the identity... it fixes the boundary (and all other points).

Comment: Well that is trivial! I am looking for  non-trivial ones.

Comment: How can I write the formula for this transformation?

Comment: $f(r,\theta)=(r,\theta+2\pi r)$

Comment: @kesa OP is looking for maps that fix every point on the boundary. The only holomorphic map that does this is the identity.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yes, my mistake..

Answer (score 6):

u can just do a rotation which tend to zero angle when you go torward the boundary and to some other angle while you are going torward the centre

Comment: How would I write such a map?

Comment: polar coordinates

Comment: Yes!..let me try.